# Create a Query using QueryBuilder with a Many-to-Many relation in Symfony2 and Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, dql, query-builder

Good evening everybody!

I've got a little problem. I would like to **filter** a query's result using a custom DQL Query in Symfony2 framework.

Here is the state of my database:

[image: Extract of the database]

I've got the SQL Query that returns the wanted result:

```
SELECT * FROM question WHERE question_id NOT IN (SELECT question_id FROM questions_joueurs WHERE joueur_id = 1)
```

I just would like to implement that in my QuestionRepository.

Thanks a lot for your next help !

**CloudCompany**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this using NOT EXISTS and MEMBER OF. Something like this

```
$qb->select('q.question_id, q.question_intitule')
    ->from('MyBundleNameSpace\Entity\Question', 'q')
    ->where('NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM MyBundleNameSpace\Entity\Jouer j WHERE j MEMBER OF q.jouers)');
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your answer FuzzyTree! It works!
I had adapted it in order to put it into my QuestionRepository.

Here is my method:

```
public function findNotAnsweredByJoueurs(Partie $partie, $level)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('q');
    $qb->where('q.level < ' . $level);
    foreach($partie->getJoueurs() as $joueur)
    {
        $qb->andWhere('NOT EXISTS (SELECT ' . $joueur->getId() . ' FROM Cloud\Bundle\MoneyDropBundle\Entity\Joueur j WHERE j MEMBER OF q.joueurs)');
    }

    return $qb->getQuery()
              ->getResult();
}
```

Comment: The foreach isn't necessary in fact you're overwriting the where condition with each iteration (to stack where conditions use 'andWhere' after the first 'where').